# Rake task - with additional class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

I have my own classes, which I want to use in my rake task.
Where to put files with this classes?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific as to what you're trying to achieve. Right now, all we can tell you is: "Somewhere where you instruct rake to find them". So if that's not sufficient, more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the classes are only used by the rake task, I'd keep them in `lib/`, just make sure you are loading the directory by configuring `autoload_paths`:

```
# application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: You don't *need* to use `autoload_paths`, you can just as easily `require` those files you need in the Rake task. By using `autoload_paths` you are forcing those files to be loaded *all the time*.

Comment: Yes, better to `require` them since they're only needed in the rake task.